# Add Event in ng-google-chart

Tags: angularjs, charts

I'm using [Angular Google Chart](https://github.com/bouil/angular-google-chart) but i do not know how to add a select event.

In the [API Doc](https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart/wiki/API-Documentation) can be seen the method 'registerWrapperListener', but i dont used it

Some idea to add select-event in this example?

Thanks you

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('google-chart-example', ['googlechart']).controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {

  var chart1 = {};
  chart1.type = "OrgChart";
  chart1.cssStyle = "height:200px; width:300px;";
  chart1.data = {
    cols: [{
      id: 'Name',
      label: 'Name',
      type: 'string'
    }, {
      id: 'Manager',
      label: 'Manager',
      type: 'string'
    }, {
      id: 'ToolTip',
      label: 'ToolTip',
      type: 'string'
    }],
    rows: [{
      c: [{
        v: '0',
        f: 'CEO'
      }, {
        v: ''
      }, {
        v: 'The CEO'
      }]
    }, {
      c: [{
        v: '1',
        f: 'worker 1'
      }, {
        v: '0'
      }, {
        v: ''
      }]
    }]
  };
  $scope.chart = chart1;

});
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">

<body ng-app="google-chart-example" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>
    <div google-chart chart="chart" style="{{chart.cssStyle}}" />
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://bouil.github.io/angular-google-chart/ng-google-chart.js"></script>
  <script src="example.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your html code, it would be:

```
<div google-chart chart="chart" style="{{chart.cssStyle}}" on-select="selectCallbackMethodYouWant(selectedItem)" />
```